# Android Gradle how to custom sourceSet in library by product flavor?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here's my main project structure:

```
App/src
 - main
 - flavor1
 - flavor2
 - dimension1
 - dimension2
 - debug
 - release
```

Both flavor* and dimension* are flavor dimensions. The build variants are:

```
flavor1Dimension1Debug
flavor1Dimension2Debug
flavor2Dimension1Debug
...
```

And library's dir structure:

```
Lib/src
 - main
 - flavor2
  - DebugInterceptor.java
 - debug
  - DebugInterceptor.java
 - release
  - DebugInterceptor.java
```

What I want:

- if variant contains 'flavor2', this variant should use `src/flavor2/DebugInterceptor.java`. It should take higher priority than build types. You can assume that these three dirs(flavor2, debug, release) contain only one file `DebugInterceptor.java`
- o.w. merging by [default build rules](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).

How can I configure gradle to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use only one dimension and multiple flavor, don't use multiple dimension or remove code from dimension, dimension is not suitable for code but for other configs like api level